# Flatten an iterable of iterables

Tags: python

How can I write `flatten` which should return every value nested in an iterable?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
for i in flatten([1, 2, [3, 4, (5, 6, 7), 8, 9], 10]):
    print(i, end=' ')
```

Expected output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: I think that if you need this, you have a problem.

Comment: Why does your question sound very similar to a homework problem?

Comment: Why "without using `itertools`? These tools are a part of the standard library for a reason!

Comment: Please do not delete your questions after receiving an answer. Unless of course, you want to get banned from asking anymore questions.

Comment: Found it, I think.  UC-Irvine, ICS-33, Problem #3: Module of Decorators (iterators), extra credit question on [flatten](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/assignments/program2/program.html).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Python 2 users have a built-in for this task:

```
from compiler.ast import flatten
```

Unfortunately, it has been removed in python 3.  You can roll your own though:

```
from collections.abc import Iterable

def flatten(collection):
    for x in collection:
        if isinstance(x, Iterable) and not isinstance(x, (str, bytes)):
            yield from flatten(x)
        else:
            yield x
```

Answer (score 6):

Homework questions with weird restrictions call for fun answers

```
import re
def function(L):
    return re.findall("[a-z0-9]+", repr(L))
```

Comment: It would be more fun if it a) didn't dig the values out of the dict aswell and b) didn't break on 0s

Comment: @wim, doh! fixed the 0 and the OP changed so there are no dicts :)

Comment: gnibbletastic .. can you show me how to use `re` to parse html?