# python/numpy versatile max function

Tags: python, numpy, max

In Python (possibly including numpy) there are various `maximum`, `max` and `amax` functions, which are to some extent covered also in some StackOverflow questions, but none of them seems to solve the rather obvious need of computing *the maximum of mixed arguments*, i.e. matching the following requirements:

- any argument could be an iterable (tuple, list, numpy array) or simply a number
- ... and recursively, i.e. any iterable could in turn contain numbers and iterables
- iterables turning out to be empty, and None items, should not affect the max
- only if all arguments are empty the output should be the given default
- if any arguments contain a NaN, that should be propagated (I think this would be automatic)

I am seeking for a solution that is versatile, compact and *proper* from a pythonic point of view.

NB. I tried to code it myself but with very little success. I would not attach the many attempts because they look ugly, and don't work either, and above all, I believe it would be misleading and a time waste for those of you who possibly can help. The question is already too long.

Anyway, here is one of my attempts, which doesn't work:

```
<!-- language: python -->

def flexMax1(aa):
    '''
    works on one argument, breaks it up into:
    - empties: eliminated
    - single numbers: replace with their max (or None)
    - iterables (if any): deal with recursively, don't forget to add the prev calc max
    '''
    # progressively replaces iterables with their max (or None if no iterables)
    M=None
    while aa:
        if M is not None:
            aa=aa.append(M)
        # eliminates empties and None, but preserves true zeros
        aa= [a for a in aa if a or a==0]

        try:
            # max of non iterables
            M=max( a for a in aa if not iterable(a) )
        except ValueError: # it is an empty sequence 
            # there weren't bare numbers, only iterables, reduce them
            aa=[ flexMax1(a) for a in aa if iterable(a) ]
        else:
            # do same, then will append the max of the iterables
            aa=[ (flexMax1(a)) for a in aa if iterable(a) ]

    return M

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(flexMax1([1]))
    print(flexMax1([1,2]))
    print(flexMax1([1,[2,3]]))
```

PS. I know that, from another standpoint, the maximum of some items should be one of those items, and that is solved by using `max`'s `key=function` optional argument. What I need is simply to return the overall maximum number

Comment: Flatten the input(s) using, for example, [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16312281/674039), and proceed with the usual builtin `max`

Answer (score 0):

You can first flatten everything down and compute the max of that:

```
import collections

def flatted(data):
    if isinstance(data, collections.Iterable):
        for element in data:
            yield from flatted(data)
    else:
        yield data

def versatile_max(data, max_function=max):
    max_function(flatted(data))
```

Comment: Interesting impleentation via generator, but, did you test it? A simple call `versatile_max([1,2])` gives `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`. I tried modifying the first if body into `for d in data: yield from flatted(d)` and in `yield [flatted(d) for d in data]`. Both eliminate the infinite recursion issue but none of them produces the intended result

Comment: Ah sorry, of course you are right. If `data` is iterable you need to iterate over it. I tested it but didn't copy pasted from the terminal. Essentially it's the same as the code in the answer that wim posted.