# how to get the unique value of a column pandas that contains list or value?

Tags: python, pandas

how to get the unique value of a column pandas  that contains list or value ?
my column:

```
column   |  column
test     |  [A,B]
test     |  [A,C]
test     |    C 
test     |    D
test     |   [E,B]
```

i want list like that :

```
list = [A, B, C, D, E]
```

thank you

Comment: What is the `dtype` of the column that contains the list?

Comment: dtype is object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply `pd.Series` to split up the lists, then `stack` and `unique`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], 'C', 'D', ['E', 'B']]})

df.col.apply(pd.Series).stack().unique().tolist()
```

Outputs

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flattening function [Credit @wim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16312281/2336654)

```
import collections

def flatten(l):
    for i in l:
        if isinstance(i, collections.abc.Iterable) and not isinstance(i, str):
            yield from flatten(i)
        else:
            yield i
```

Then use `set`

```
list(set(flatten(df.B)))

['A', 'B', 'E', 'C', 'D']
```

---

### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    B=[['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], 'C', 'D', ['E', 'B']]
))
```